# Dependency Header file needs to be included in c , even with Forward declaration in main header file

Tags: c, visual-c++, windows-kernel

I have a 3 header files, foo.h, bar.h & FooBar.h. And a C-source file named bar.c.

in FooBar.h

```
#pragma once

#include "bar.h"
```

in foo.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "FooBar.h"

typedef struct _A
{
   char a;
}A;
```

in bar.h

```
#pragma once 

/* other includes except foo.h as including that will cause circular dependency */

typedef struct _A A; //line1 - forward-declared type

void func(A* aObj);
```

in bar.c

```
#include "foo.h" //line2
#include "bar.h"

void func(A* aObj)
{
    if('\0' == aObj->a)
        aObj->a = 'A';
}
```

Now in **bar.c**, I want to remove inclusion of **foo.h**, as I have already forward declared the _A in **bar.h**. So, when I comment that out, I am getting below error (when hovering over aObj):

`pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed` in function  **func()** in **bar.c** where I am trying to manipulate the **aObj**.

And after compiling the error points to

`C2037: left of 'aObj' specifies undefined struct/union '_A'.`

So, how do I make sure that, I dont have to use the both:

1. Forward declaration in **bar.h** (//line1 above)
2. Include **foo.h** in **bar.c** (//line2 above)

Comment: Include guards maybe??

Comment: Yes, I have #pragma once in both the header files

Comment: "I have already forward declared the _A in bar.h." I do not see that forward declaration inside bar.h. Can you refer more precisely? Maybe write a comment `/* forward declaration of _A */`. Note, I am looking for something like `struct _A;` but only see a typedef using `struct _A` instead of forward declaring it.

Comment: Marked //line1 in bar.h

Comment: Line 1 in bar.h is using _A instead of forward declaring it.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Seeing line at least 5 commented as line 1 makes me doubt the shown code. Also everything inside `<>`  should either be removed completly or serve the MRE and be complete enough for that. If your problem occurs with only one .c file, then your MRE can also be in one piece.

Comment: You are aware that the only thing you can do with a forward-declared type is to make pointers to it, aren't you?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_A`) and are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: Yes I am aware.

Comment: @Yunnosch,  I have tried with ```struct _A;``` as well. With same result.

Comment: If you are aware that pointers is the only thing, then why do you attempt to access the forward-declared type?

Comment: I have a Global structure that houses other internal structures. When I want to manipulate an element in one of the specific internal structures (in a function, and in a different source file than where the global structure is present), I will be passing the starting address of the internal structure, instead of the full Global structure. 
That's why I am trying to access forward-declared pointer's elements. I dont know if I answered your question.

Comment: You need to show us what `function` is actually doing!!

Comment: @PaulSanders

the function is doing this:
```aObj->a = 'A';``` . I updated the function code above in the question.

Comment: Then that's your problem.  Without seeing a full definition of `_A`, you can't dereference a pointer to `aObj` (as others have been saying).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now in bar.c, I want to remove inclusion of foo.h, as I have already forward declared the _A in bar.h

You don't want to do that, because `func` needs to see the *definition* of `struct _A` in order to work with it, and that definition resides in foo.h.

So bar.c *must* include foo.h.

Comment: ok. edited code to include the full picture with one mode header called "FooBar.h" that includes "bar.h" & "foo.h" includes "FooBar.h".This is the kind of Circular dependency I was talking about.

Comment: @APK That doesn't change anything.  bar.c still needs to include foo.h.

Comment: @APK Here's how the compiler sees bar.c with foo.h included: https://godbolt.org/z/bKoshMGb5 . And here's how the compiler sees bar.c without including foo.h: https://godbolt.org/z/vWMabW1zM . There is no way for `func` to know `aObj` has a member named `a`.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks, that makes sense

Comment: @dbush - thanks for the reply, I understood what was the problem, with your answer.

Comment: @dbush, this means that, I have to have,

1) The forward declaration in bar.h (to avoid the circular dependency) AND, 
2) Include "foo.h" in bar.c (to let compiler know about the definition of struct, when trying to assign some value to aObj->a). 

Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @APK Correct, you need to do both.